# Find the size of a multipart/form-data file in mule4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a HTTP Listener which will read the file in multipart/form-data format. I want to find the size of that file and check if it is less/greater than 10 MB. Please help me with this

Comment: Inside Mule, the moment you can get the size you already read the full file. So, if someone sends an infinite file it will make your system crash. Does it still make sense to get the file size or you need a better solution?

Comment: The requirement is to raise an exception if the file size is greater than 10MB. What can i do in this case ?

Comment: Do you want to check the file size to prevent a system crash because of some Out Of Memory exception? Or you are not worried about that but only wants to check that because you do not want to accept >10 MB file.

Comment: @HarshankBansal Yeah, I only want to check that because I don't want to accept > 10MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
sizeOf(payload.parts.file.content.^raw)
```

Where file is the key for what is being sent.

Comment: You have to be aware that as @Jorge Garcia said, the attachement will be fully read into memory, and it might consume more memory to process it, so be mindful of not running out of memory.

Comment: IIRC, sizeOf would  read into chunks of 16Kb  to calculate the size of the file, i.e. if the file is Binary ( and would not load it fully into memory) ... 

I had implemented a solution in Mule3 (probably 5-6 years ago)  for this ask , via a custom policy and would rewind the stream (after consuming it in small chunks) and if it would not exceed the size it would all go through , but if it would exceed the size it would return a HTTP 500. The amount/size of the chunk was a configuration of the custom policy.

Comment: I meant that for Mule 4 the HTTP connector reads attachments in memory, doesn't stream them, before DataWeave starts executing.

Comment: HTTP Listener does stream the content for supported formats (like multipart/form-data) and it is not loaded in memory until you start to consume it.

Comment: And as @SalimKhan Mentioned that ```sizeOf``` does not load the entire content in memory if the payload allows streaming. I just want to add to this statement that the reason for this is, by default, the HTTP Listener's streaming strategy is ```repeatable-file-store-stream```. If you set it to ```repeatable-in-memory-stream``` the content has to be loaded in memory.
HTTP Listener Ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-documentation#listener